# Using Power Query, apply filter to show only highest values

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I am attempting to have only the latest revision (AKA REV on the picture below) show up. These will always be letters. I know how to sort them by that but I want to throw out the lower revisions.

[image]

Comment: Just use a filter

Comment: The problem is that the data is dynamic and the highest revision will change. I need it to find the highest value and only allow that to show up

Comment: What column has the values? ECOLevel?

Comment: the column "REV"

Comment: What do you mean by highest values?

Comment: If the possible revisions are just single letters, you can use list.max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the issue is trying to figure out the "latest" revision, when using alpha characters instead of numbers as the revision marker. Assuming the more characters the higher the revision, and Z > A, then this should work in powerquery

Load data into powerquery  (data .. table from ... [x] use as headers)

Add column .. custom column...named **dupe**  with formula :

```
= try Number.From( List.Accumulate(Text.ToList([REV]), "", (state, current)=> state&Number.ToText(Character.ToNumber(current), "0"))) otherwise null
```

that will convert the text REV to a number.

Use arrows atop the **dupe** column to filter [x] for a single value.  Edit the resulting formula in the formula bar to end similarly to this which compares to the max value:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([dupe] = List.Max(#"Added Custom"[dupe])))
```

Right click to remove extra column. File .. close and load ..

sample full code if your data is in Table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "dupe", each try Number.From( List.Accumulate(Text.ToList([REV]), "", (state, current)=> state&Number.ToText(Character.ToNumber(current), "0"))) otherwise null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([dupe] = List.Max(#"Added Custom"[dupe]))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"dupe"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you need to filter the highest value in REV column:

```
= Table.SelectRows(YourTable, let a = List.Max(YourTable[REV]) in each [REV] = a)
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I get the error "Expression.SyntaxError: Token RightParen expected."

Comment: So you've missed the right parenthesis, just put it in the proper place)

Comment: Now it results in "Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation."

Comment: Make sure you refer the same table from your previous step (YourTable in my example) in both places of the formula.

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand how the power queries work. This is the current advanced editor code

```let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("H:\tvolmer\Production Planner\Data\SN Flow Tracking Data\FullSNList.csv"),[Delimiter=",",Encoding=1252]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"State"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Config", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each ([Config] = ConfigParameter))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"```

Comment: If Config column contains only letters and you still need to filter the last letter, this code for #"Filtered Rows" step should work:  = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", let a = List.Max(#"Sorted Rows"[Config]) in each [Config] = a)